# Why do we use @ and + symbol for creating id of a widget in Android?

Tags: android

What is the exact meaning of using @ and + symbol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The at-symbol (@) at the beginning of
>   the string indicates that the XML
>   parser should parse and expand the
>   rest of the ID string and identify it
>   as an ID resource. The plus-symbol (+)
>   means that this is a new resource name
>   that must be created and added to our
>   resources (in the R.java file)

Source: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#id

Answer (score 2):

see the android docs http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#id